# Как распарсить json в джаве?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть json следующего вида:

```json
{
  "links": ["example","example"...],

  "abbr": {"short": "long_variant", "short": "long_variant"...}
}
```

Как его распарсить с помощью `jackson`?

```java
class MyJson {
  String[] links;
  Map<String, String> abbr;
}

....

MyJson hdata = mapper.readTree(file, MyJson.class);
```

Пробовал так, но это просто выдает ошибку.

Comment: 1 - укажите конкретную ошибку, которая возникает. 2 - в json не должно быть двух одинаковых ключей  в одном объекте ("short" в данном случае)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [`ObjectMapper::readTree`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.io.File)) принимает только один входной параметр и возвращает экземпляр класса [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html).

Для получения объекта из файла следует использовать метод [`ObjectMapper::readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.io.File,%20java.lang.Class)).
Кроме того, у класса `MyJson` должны быть определены геттеры/сеттеры (вручную либо при помощи Lombok-аннотаций `@Data` или `@Getter`/`@Setter`).

То есть, изменённый код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```java
public class MyJson {
    String[] links;
    Map<String, String> abbr;

    public String[] getLinks() {return links;}
    public Map<String, String> getAbbr() {return abbr;}

    public void setLinks(String[] links) { this.links = links;}
    public void setAbbr(Map<String, String> abbr) { this.abbr = abbr;}
}
```

```java
public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File file = new File("my.json");
    MyJson obj = mapper.readValue(file, MyJson.class);
    // ...
}
```

Также следует учесть, что ключи в мапе должны быть уникальными для корректной десериализации, как отметил в комментарии @insolor.